# Check what number a string ends with in Python

Tags: python, string, numbers

Such as "example123" would be 123, "ex123ample" would be None, and "123example" would be None.

Comment: can the number be negative or have decimal points?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression, something like `/(\d+)$/`. This will match and capture one or more digits, anchored at the end of the string.

Read about [regular expressions in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: +use `int` to cast the extracted string to an integer.

Comment: @Steve, you'd better get into the habit of using raw strings (`r'...'`) for your regular expressions, otherwise you'll soon be entering into a world of pain…

Comment: In addition, no need to add parentheses around the match as `group(0)` or `group()` returns the whole match anyway.

Answer (score 35):

You can use regular expressions from the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module:

```
import re
def get_trailing_number(s):
    m = re.search(r'\d+$', s)
    return int(m.group()) if m else None
```

The `r'\d+$'` string specifies the expression to be matched and consists of these [special symbols](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

- `\d`: a digit (0-9)
- `+`: one or more of the previous item (i.e. `\d`)
- `$`: the end of the input string

In other words, it tries to find one or more digits at the end of a string. The `search()` function returns a `Match` object containing various information about the match or `None` if it couldn't match what was requested. The `group()` method, for example, returns the whole substring that matched the regular expression (in this case, some digits).

The ternary `if` at the last line returns either the matched digits converted to a number or None, depending on whether the Match object is None or not.

Answer (score -2):

Oops, correcting (sorry, I missed the point)

you should do something like this ;)

Import the RE module

```
import re
```

Then write a regular expression, "searching" for an expression.

```
s = re.search("[a-zA-Z+](\d{3})$", "string123")
```

This will return "123" if match or NoneType if not.

```
s.group(0)
```

Comment: Yep. I couldn't agree more. ;(

Comment: Much better :), though your regex is overkill.

Comment: Not working for me as it is returning `'g123'`. You could use `s.group(1)` to make it working but you could also make it simpler.