# while animating using multiple images the image does weird snap can't explain properly

Tags: python, pygame

whenever i run this code the animation runs somewhat smoothly but from what it seems like when the temp gets to length of the list and goes back to zero the image blinks

its not that the images that are being animated not synced properly i made a gif to see if the images had some framing issue but there are none in gif the animation is smooth

[replit example with images](https://replit.com/@SunischitDahal/pygame-example#main.py)

```
import pygame,os

pygame.init()
window=pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
run=[]
for image in os.listdir("run"):
    run.append(
        pygame.transform.scale(
            pygame.image.load("run/" + image),
            (40, 40),
        ).convert_alpha()
    )

temp=0
diff=0.2
index=0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            

    temp+=diff
    if temp>=len(run):
        temp=0
    index=int(temp)
    print(index)
    window.fill("white")

    window.blit(run[index],(300,300))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns the images in arbitrary order. So I suggest to sort the list of filenames:

```py
images = os.listdir("run")
images.sort()
for image in images:
    # [...]
```

However, you need to change the names of the images. The images are sorted alphabetically by their name:

```
survivor-run_0.png
survivor-run_1.png
survivor-run_10.png
survivor-run_11.png
survivor-run_12.png
survivor-run_13.png
survivor-run_14.png
survivor-run_15.png
survivor-run_16.png
survivor-run_17.png
survivor-run_18.png
survivor-run_19.png
survivor-run_2.png
survivor-run_3.png
...
```

Change the names:

```
survivor-run_00.png
survivor-run_01.png
survivor-run_02.png
survivor-run_03.png
survivor-run_04.png
survivor-run_05.png
survivor-run_06.png
survivor-run_07.png
survivor-run_08.png
survivor-run_09.png
survivor-run_10.png
survivor-run_11.png
survivor-run_12.png
...
```

---

Alternatively you can use regular expression to sort the names (see [Check what number a string ends with in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085512/check-what-number-a-string-ends-with-in-python)). Write a function that returns the tailing number of the filename:

```py
import re

def get_trailing_number(s):
    m = re.search(r'\d+$', s)
    return int(m.group()) if m else None
```

Sort the list of using that function:

```py
images = os.listdir("run")
images.sort(key = lambda name: get_trailing_number(name))
for image in images:
    # [...]
```